# Can Aforge detect the tablet type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tablet, aforge

Team,

I have an issue where i have to deploy the C# web cam project done with the help of **Aforge classes** on two **tablets Pro -3 and Pro -4.**  Issue is that there are vast differences between the video resolutions of each of the them. I need to select 960 * 540 for Pro-3 and  640 * 640 for Pro-4.

if i know something as if(tablet is Pro-3)
                            then
                             set video resolution as 960 * 540
                       if tablet is Pro4
                             set video resolution as 640 * 640

is there any way i can accomplish this

Question 2)

I also have a picturebox control which seem to be bigger than the video resolution. How can i set the picturebox size and width to video resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> Can Aforge detect the tablet type?

I don't think it can. But it can be done in different way.

**As for your first question**.
I don't have any of these models to check this but you should get model by executing this powershell script:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem | Format-List model
```

C# code for retriving Model and Manufacturer would be something like:

```
public static string GetDeviceManufacturerModel()
    {
        const string manufacturerKey = "Manufacturer";
        const string modelKey = "Model";

        var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            string.Format("select {0}, {1} from Win32_ComputerSystem", manufacturerKey, modelKey));

        foreach (var managementObject in mos.Get())
        {
            if (managementObject[manufacturerKey] != null && managementObject[modelKey] != null)
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", managementObject[manufacturerKey], managementObject[modelKey]);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**As for second question**. Aforge library that you use is giving you [VideoSourcePlayer](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/bd272e5f-344c-56a5-f74f-1ac3062a9554.htm), there is `AutoSizeControl` Property designed for achiving what you want. Maybe it's better solution for you than picturebox.

If not, check out this thread on Aforge forum : [PictureBox instead of VideoSourcePlayer](http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1981)